# How to update pip in python3 in aws instance ec2

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

I applied this command

```
 pip install --upgrade pip
```

The package shows error in installing python package:

```
Collecting pip   
Permission denied: 

 **You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install
 --upgrade pip' command.**
```

This command is not working in my aws ec2 linux terminal

Answer (score 2):

This command should work

```
 python -m pip install -U pip
```

If this doesn't work and you get a permission error use this

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user
```

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-87-24 ~]$ python -m pip install -U
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
You are using pip 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.0
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: You haven't used the full command, you tried `python -m pip install -U` the command you should try is `python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: python --version
Python 2.7.16
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-87-24 ~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-87-24 ~]$

Comment: Bro first of all stop pasting the entire terminal, it's exposing your IP, just copy the command that I have entered and it should work, if it doesn't just respond with the output, not your terminal IP.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade `pip` globally (i.e. for all users), you need `sudo` rights:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `sudo` privileges you can still upgrade it for the current user:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```